# continuing loops a thing in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am carrying out another exercise to learn various things about Oracle SQL's syntax today's lesson I've chosen are loops. Please see below code where I am trying to have two fields (temp variables) having values being decreased until it's less than zero depending on which of the variables hit's zero depends on what text I would like to output into the script output. Hopefully it makes sense. If I have made any faux pas's please do shout at me.

```
DECLARE
        "Character"         VARCHAR2(255);
        "Enemy"             VARCHAR2(255);
        "Character_Health"  NUMBER;
        "Enemy_Health"      NUMBER;
        "Character_Attack"  NUMBER;
        "Enemy_Attack"      NUMBER;


BEGIN -- Generates Base Stats


        SELECT 'Hero'       INTO "Character"        FROM dual;
        SELECT 'Villain'    INTO "Enemy"            FROM dual;
        SELECT 100          INTO "Character_Health" FROM dual;
        SELECT 25           INTO "Enemy_Health"     FROM dual;
        SELECT 10           INTO "Character_Attack" FROM dual;
        SELECT 5            INTO "Enemy_Attack"     FROM dual;

        dbms_output.put_line    ("Character" || ' (' || "Character_Health" || ') VS ' ||' '|| "Enemy" || ' (' || "Enemy_Health" || ')') ;
        dbms_output.put_line    ('');
        dbms_output.put_line    ('FIGHT!');

    BEGIN -- Round 1

            LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line    ('');

            SELECT "Enemy_Health" - "Character_Attack" INTO "Enemy_Health" FROM dual; -- Hero hits Villain
            dbms_output.put_line    ("Character" || ' Hits ' || "Enemy" || ' for ' || "Character_Attack" ||' Damage' ); 
            dbms_output.put_line    ("Enemy" || ' Has ' || "Enemy_Health" || ' Health Remaining ');

            CASE WHEN "Enemy_Health" < 0 THEN dbms_output.put_line ("Enemy" || 'Has Fainted' || "Character" || 'Wins!'); 
            ELSE CONTINUE;
            EXIT WHEN "Enemy_Health" < 0;

            SELECT "Character_Health" - "Enemy_Attack" INTO "Character_Health" FROM dual; -- Villain hits Hero
            dbms_output.put_line    ('');
            dbms_output.put_line    ("Enemy" || ' Hits ' || "Character" || ' for ' || "Enemy_Attack" ||' Damage' );
            dbms_output.put_line    ("Character" || ' Has ' || "Character_Health" || ' Health Remaining ');

            CASE WHEN "Character_Health" < 0 THEN dbms_output.put_line ("Character" || 'Has Fainted' || "Enemy" || 'Wins!'); 
            ELSE CONTINUE;
            EXIT WHEN "Character_Health" < 0;

            END LOOP;
    END;            
END;
```

Comment: What is your question? You've posted some code but you haven't said what problem you are having with it. Is it erroring? Not doing what you expected? Something else?

Comment: It seems that you should practice some more elementary things first. You have several CASE statements that are missing the END CASE clause. Assignment to a variable can be made with `variable := value`, you don't need to select the value from dual into the variable. Etc. Start with the elementary things before you jump to loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some errors
1. Syntax for case is:

```
CASE [ expression ]

   WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN condition_n THEN result_n

   [ELSE result]

END CASE
```

Learn more:
- [simple case statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-3937FEB2-96A1-456B-AD9E-09B627DF0939) 
- [searched case statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-C7CBBE66-5E51-444E-BE92-C23ED662FE4D)

2. `CONTINUE` stops processing loop and starts it from the begining, so your logic is corrupt - only Hero is attacking.
3. You need space after "Fainted"
4. It's better to use IF in this case:

   ```
   IF "Character_Health" < 0
   THEN
     dbms_output.put_line ("Character" || 'Has Fainted. ' || "Enemy" || 'Wins!');
     EXIT; 
   END IF;
   ```
5. It's not mistake, but you don't need `select into from dual` if you want to change value of variable.
6. Last but not least- i don't like how you use variables. "Character_Health" is similar to 'Character_Health' or '''Character_Health'''. Better use names like characterHealth or character_health.

My version would be something like that:

```
    DECLARE
        v_Character         VARCHAR2(255) := 'Hero' ;
        v_Enemy             VARCHAR2(255) := 'Villain';
        v_Character_Health  NUMBER := 100;
        v_Enemy_Health      NUMBER := 25;
        v_Character_Attack  NUMBER := 10;
        v_Enemy_Attack      NUMBER := 5;
        v_nl                VARCHAR2(1) := chr(10);
    BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line    (v_Character || ' (' || v_Character_Health || ') VS ' ||' '|| v_Enemy || ' (' || v_Enemy_Health || ')' || v_nl) ;
        dbms_output.put_line    ('FIGHT!' || v_nl);

        LOOP
        v_Enemy_Health := v_Enemy_Health - v_Character_Attack;
        dbms_output.put_line    (v_Character || ' Hits ' || v_Enemy || ' for ' || v_Character_Attack ||' Damage' ); 
        dbms_output.put_line    (v_Enemy || ' Has ' || v_Enemy_Health || ' Health Remaining' || v_nl);
        IF v_Enemy_Health < 0 THEN dbms_output.put_line (v_Enemy || 'Has Fainted. ' || v_Character || 'Wins!'); EXIT;
        END IF;

        v_Character_Health := v_Character_Health - v_Enemy_Attack;
        dbms_output.put_line    (v_Enemy || ' Hits ' || v_Character || ' for ' || v_Enemy_Attack || ' Damage' );
        dbms_output.put_line    (v_Character || ' Has ' || v_Character_Health || ' Health Remaining' || v_nl);

        IF v_Character_Health < 0 THEN dbms_output.put_line (v_Character || 'Has Fainted. ' || v_Enemy || 'Wins!'); EXIT; 
        END IF;

        END LOOP;           
END;
/
```

Comment: Your first point isn't quite right; the OP is using a [searched case statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-C7CBBE66-5E51-444E-BE92-C23ED662FE4D) (but is missing `end case;`) rather than a [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-216F1B33-493F-4CDE-93BB-096BACA8523E).